# Print stack in C++

Tags: c++

Considet this code:

```
#include <iostream>

void overflower(const int *startAddress)
{
    int j = 0;  
    std::cout << uintptr_t(&j) - uintptr_t(startAddress) 
    << ": stack bottom : " << startAddress << ", current : " << &j <<'\n';
    overflower(&j);
}

int main()
{
    const int i = 0;
    const int* startAddress = &i;

    std::cout << uintptr_t(&i) - uintptr_t(startAddress)   
    << ": stack bottom : " << startAddress << ", current : " << &i <<'\n';

    overflower(&i);
}
```

I expect it to output the difference between startAddress and the currentAddress of the stack.

However for some reason it looks like startAddress is also increased while the stack grows.

I get output like this:

```
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc752254, current : 0x7ffddc752224
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc752224, current : 0x7ffddc7521f4
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc7521f4, current : 0x7ffddc7521c4
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc7521c4, current : 0x7ffddc752194
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc752194, current : 0x7ffddc752164
18446744073709551568: stack bottom : 0x7ffddc752164, current : 0x7ffddc752134
```

So in short. Why is the startAddress beeing modified instead of staying const?

Comment: Because you call `overflower` with the address of the current invocation's `j` variable. Did you mean to call `overflower(startAddress)` ?

Comment: Also, the stack very probably grows down on your platform, so `j - startAddress` is negative, which is a very large number when interpreted as a `uintptr_t`.

Comment: direction seems to be fine. and yes overflower should call startAddress. One of these mistakes to stupid to spot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments.

it should be

`overflower(startAddress);`

than we get the output:

```
174505: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda8241844
174506: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda8241814
174507: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda82417e4
174508: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda82417b4
174509: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda8241784
174510: stack bottom : 0x7ffda8a3e814, current : 0x7ffda8241754
Segmentation fault
```

and can see the size of the stack the line before segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour when you do

```
uintptr_t(&j) - uintptr_t(startAddress)
```

because it computes the difference between addresses of variables that are unrelated (not in the same array or class/structure).

Comment: uintptr_t is an unsigned integral type, so its perfectly valid to do arithmetic on it.

Comment: The problem is not the arithmetic, it's the compare of pointers to objects that are not in the same array. There's no guarantee the distance in memory to be meaningful

Comment: I thought they are both on the stack and we print the stack difference here

Comment: @Sandro4912 Once undefined behavior is invoked, all bets are off as to the behavior of the program.

Comment: @Sandro4912 the standard doesn't mention a stack

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I dont understand where the undefined behavoir is coming from. We're converting 2 pointers to uintptr_ts which is perectly well defined. Were then doing some math on two unsigned integral values which is well defined. Sure the analysis of what the result of that maths means might be wrong but there's nothing strictly undefined about anything here. As _undefined behavoir_ has a strict meaning in C++ which I dont think this falls under, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jeffrey "_undefined behavoir_" has a strict meaning in C++. And that meaning is definately _not_ "no guarantee to be meaningful". There's nothing which is undefined behaviour here if I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: @MikeVine you are right. One thing that wasn't clear to me: `&j - startAddress` is UB.  `uintptr_t(&j) - uintptr_t(startAddress)` is merely implementation defined. Thanks for the clarification. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757409/is-calculating-address-difference-undefined-behaviour