# Is calculating address difference undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Let's say I perform the following:

```
void g(int* x)
{
    int y = 0;
    auto diff = uintptr_t(&y) - uintptr_t(x);
}

void f()
{
    int x = 0;
    g(&x);
}
```

Does `diff` merely have undefined value, or does the code invoke undefined behaviour? According to the specification, is the code guaranteed to run nicely and compute a value for `diff`, possibly meaningless, or does it invoke UB? I believe there's something about unrelated variables, but could not pinpoint it.

I'm interested in answers regarding any standard since (including) C++ 11.

Discussion arose from comments in: [Print stack in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61752890/print-stack-in-c/61753246)

Comment: See: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#5

Comment: @NathanOliver - That applies to the pointers themselves, not to integers obtained from them.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - The code is not subtracting **pointers**.

Comment: std::ptrdiff_t there's a type defined

Comment: @QuentinUK That's not useful here. Without the conversion to `uintptr_t`, your subtraction would have undefined behaviour due to not being constrained to the bounds of a single object/array. Indeed, that's the whole reason `uintptr_t` is being used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote the C++11 standard draft. On the subject of converting a pointer to an integer

> **[expr.reinterpret.cast]**
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#5) A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly
>   converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of
>   sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to
>   the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between
>   pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.

Since `uintptr_t` must be defined for the your code to compile, then there exists an integer type on the target machine capable of being the target of the pointer-to-integer conversion. The mapping is implementation defined, but most importantly the result is not indeterminate. This means you obtain some valid integer for both conversions.

So the subtraction is not undefined behavior. But the result is implementation defined.

Comment: This is super helpful. I didn't realize how important the cast to uintptr_t was. If the code did `&y - x` directly would the answer still hold?

Comment: @Jeffrey - No. Subtracting the pointers directly is plain undefined. Nathan Oliver's comment under your post has the relevant standard passage.

Answer (score 5):

Converting pointer to integer of sufficient size is well defined, subtracting unsigned integer from another is well defined regardless of their value. There is no undefined behaviour here.

But also, standard doesn't guarantee any particular value for the converted integers, and therefore neither for the result of their subtraction.